# Is there a way to make the first line of a four-line gloss not have gloss alignment spacing?

Tags: linguistics, gb4e, cgloss4e

I was wondering if there was a way to make the first line in a four-line interlinear gloss not conform to glossing alignment/gloss spacing.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{gb4e,cgloss}
\usepackage{leipzig}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
\ex \label{label}\glll awúuassshiichih \\
awuua- ss- shiichi -h \\
inside.{\Noun}- {\Goal}- throw -{\Imp} \\
\glt `Throw it in [the] inside! [of the hoop]' %\citation
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

The first of the four lines is simply the example in the examined language. Thus, I do not need it to align with the spacing below.

However, the word on the first line (/awúuassshiichih/) aligns with the first word on the second and third lines. This is fine, but it results in the second words on the 2nd and 3rd lines being pushed all the way to the end of (/awúuassshiichih/).

Is there a way for me to avoid this?

I am using the newest updates of TeXMaker, MacTeX2020, and MacOS.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The example does not compile. Where is `cgloss.sty` available?

Comment: @egreg Available here: https://staticweb.hum.uu.nl/medewerkers/alexis.dimitriadis/latex/cgloss.sty but there are other things wrong with the code that make it not compile.

Comment: I'm sorry! It's from a much larger file and I was trying to make the example minimal. I'm not sure what to add/what is missing in terms of compilability...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution to this is to not use a three line gloss, but instead use a two line gloss with a simple `\\` to end the first line. I've adjusted your code to make it compilable.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{leipzig}
\usepackage{gb4e,cgloss}

\newleipzig{noun}{n}{noun}
\newleipzig{goal}{go}{goal}

\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex \label{label}
awúuassshiichih\\
\gll awuua- ss- shiichi -h \\
inside.{\Noun}- {\Goal}- throw -{\Imp} \\
\glt `Throw it in [the] inside! [of the hoop]' %\citation
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Is there any reason you can think of that mine would include an oversized space between awúuassshiichih and the first gloss line? The space between the final gloss line and the translation is normal, so I think that means cgloss is working... TIA!

Comment: @Noah Strange. That big space is indicative of not having loaded `cgloss`.  Do you get the big space with my sample document, or only your actual document?

Comment: Only in mine--yours worked great when I ran it alone.

Comment: When I remove cgloss, I get the weird spacing between the translation and the gloss, plus even more extra spacing between the preamble and the gloss, if that helps at all.

Comment: Isn't it easier to load `leipzig` before `gb4e` than mixing package loading with declarations?

Comment: @egreg Sure. That's probably better style.

Comment: @Noah Perhaps you are using `setspace` for double spacing? If so, add `\singlespacing` within the `{exe}` environment.  Otherwise, you'll need to do some detective work with your actual document to see what might be causing the extra space.

Comment: Yes!! Thank you so much!